Plex error Unavailable Media - The Plex Media Server can't find or access the media file for this library item at the expected location
I have a Plex Media Server running on macOS. I watch the files from my Apple TV and iPad.
Occasionally, once every week or two, when trying to play media files they are marked in red as "Unavailable" and I get the error:

Unavailable Media
The Plex Media Server can't find or access the media file for this library item at the expected location


If I'm home, I go to my Mac and restart Plex. This immediately fixes the issue.
But if I'm away from home, I'm unable to watch anything on my Plex server.
What is the cause of this issue, and how do I prevent it from happening? Is there any way to fix the issue remotely?
